# How to implement jQuery val() for a span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, html

I have a few select elements that are grouped by a span. I'm creating a plugin to do some interaction with the elements. Now I would like to give my users the support of the `val()` function, so that they are able to get or set the 'value' of my span. Setting the value will result in the select box element to change en getting the value will result in the addition of the selectbox values.

Basically I would like my *plugin* to add the support for the `val()` method. Any ideas on how to implement this?

**Code**

```
<span id="test">
    <select id="one">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="two">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

**Challange** 
Get the following code to work: `$('#test').val('1:1');` and `$('#test').val()`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to override `val()` (as you will have to fiddle with what the original `.val()` does) but +1 for an interesting question

Comment: Okay the main question is how to override *val()* not how to implement your specific task?

Comment: @DanielB: true. I would like to override, support or otherwise implement the `val()` in my plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full plugin and I did not override `val()` but it should do what you want.

```
$.fn.value = function(value) {
    if (value) {
        var s = value.split(':');
        for ( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ ) {
            this.find('select').eq(i).val(s[i]);
        }
    } else {
        var result = [];
        this.find('select').each( function( index, item ) {
            result.push($(item).val());
        });

        return result.join(':');

    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#test").value("2:2");
    alert($("#test").value());
});
```

You can try it at http://jsfiddle.net/QBSWm/1/

Comment: +1, most complete approach.. But to fit the OP you could store the original `val` reference and then check if `this.is(':input')` and use the original `val`, otherwise your code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [InputMask](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/inputmask) jquery plugin. What they do is to store original jquery `val()` function in a variable and replace it with their own. Then you will receive the call first, you can check if the element is `span`, and if so return it **otherwise call the original function**.

```
var originalVal = $.fn.val;

$.fn.val = function(params){
   // if span then return your logic
   // otherwise call originalVal 
}
```

Comment: Interesting... I'll have a look at the code. I would like to be able to redirect the `val` only for certain elements. Hahaha... maybe it would be easier by just writing a value attribute ;-).

Comment: Seems to be the most risky, true answer :-).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is risky but I though doing a jquery plugin, you have to modify jquery itself. I am sorry I did not provide code sample but I suppose it pointed you to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good idea to mess with jQuery like this, and there may be some typing errors, but here you go:

```
var oldVal = jQuery.fn.val;
jQuery.fn.extend({
    val: function(value) { 
        // replace class check below with something related to your span
        if (this.length == 1 && this.is('span.my-custom-class')) { 
            if (arguments.length == 0) {
                // below is just a sample, traverse 
                // child selects like in DanielB's answer
                // and return the value you expect
                return this.attr('justsomesample');                 
            }
            else {
               this.attr('justsomesample', value); 
               return this;
            }
        }; 
        return oldVal.apply(this, arguments); }});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .text() JQuery function instead of .val() JQuery function to change your span.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good iead to override `.val()`, but if you really want a `.val()` like method for span, you could just add following code :

```
$.fn.sval = function(value) {
   if(!value)
       return $(this).html();
   else
       return $(this).html(value);
}
```

and then, to use it, just like .val() :

```
// Get value
alert($('#test').sval());
// Set value
$('#test').sval("yo");
```

Comment: this just mimics the `.html()` method. (*not what the OP asks for*)